# iComparable Interface Workings

Tags: c#, icomparable

I have created a Customer class with iComparable Interface.

```
public class Customer: IComparable<Customer>
{
    public int ID {set; get;}
    public string Name {set; get;}
    public int Salary {set; get;}

    public int CompareTo(Customer obj)
    {
      if (this.Salary > obj.Salary)
          return 1;
        else if
            (this.Salary < obj.Salary)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
     }

}
```

In the main program I have created a List of customers and added three customers.

```
List<Customer> ListCust = new List<Customer>(); 
ListCust.Add(Cust1);
ListCust.Add(Cust2);
ListCust.Add(Cust3);
```

I then sort the list.

```
ListCust.Sort();
```

My question is how is this sort method of list picking up the "CompareTo" part of the Customer class. Initially when I had tried to sort it without the iComparable interface it was giving me invalid operation error.

The following question is why cant I just make a "CompareTo" method in the customer class without iComparable interface and make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason .NET could not "just" sort your `Customer` objects is because it has no way of guessing in what way you want to sort them: by salary, by first name, by last name, by the time they placed their first order, etc.

However, you can make it work without implementing `IComparable` in three different ways:

- **[Pass a separate `IComparer<Customer>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) implementation** - this lets you move comparison logic to a separate class, and apply different comparison logics based on a situation.
- **[Pass a `Comparison<Customer>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate** - same as above, but now you don't need a separate class; this lets you provide comparison logic in a lambda.
- **Use LINQ's [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead** - Similar to above, but gives you additional capabilities (filtering, projecting, grouping, etc.)

Comment: Thank you. For my first question, am I correct in saying that the sort method in the List collection looks for an implementation of CompareTo method of the iComparable?

Comment: @user3186277 Ultimately, yes, although it does not do so directly. It tries to get a default comparer through `Comparer<Customer>.Default`, which first tries `IComparable<Customer>` and then goes for non-generic `IComparable`. If both attempts fail, sort throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

The `Sort` method checks whether the type parameter implements `IComparable`. If it does, the method casts each item in the list to `IComparable`. Something like this: (Might not be how they *actually* did it, but you get the idea.)

```
foreach (T item in this) {
    if (item is IComparable) {
        var castedItem = (IComparable)item;
        // do other things with castedItem
    } else {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sorting is not supported");
    }
}
```

So if you don't implement `IComparable`, `item is IComparable` evaluates to false so that's why an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown.

Thus, the ultimate reason is...

> The source code doesn't check whether you have a `CompareTo` method or not. It just checks whether you have the interface implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `Sort` method, it says

> InvalidOperationException is thrown when comparer is null, and the default comparer Comparer.Default cannot find implementation of the IComparable generic interface or the IComparable interface for type T.

It was designed this way.